# Why can't I get the same instance of class when I have used remember in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After I run the code A, I find `s1.hashCode()` and `s2.hashCode()` return different values after UI recomposition.

I have added `remember` keyword for the function `rememberOtherState()`, why can't I get the same instance of class when I have used remember in Android Jetpack Compose ?

```
class OtherState (context: Context) {
    ...
}

@Composable
fun rememberOtherState(): OtherState {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    return remember {
        OtherState(context)
    }
}


@Composable
fun TitleWithToolBar(   
) {
    val s1=rememberOtherState()
    val s2=rememberOtherState()
    
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier            
    ) {

        log(s1.hashCode().toString()+" S1")
        log(s2.hashCode().toString()+" S2")

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remember` is positional. Every call to `rememberOtherState` will return a different instance of `OtherState` but will return the same instance every time `TitleWithToolBar` is recomposed.

For more details on positional memoization and consider reading: https://newsletter.jorgecastillo.dev/p/positional-memoization-in-jetpack